# convert List<T> 's one property to comma separated item

Tags: c#, sql, collections

My database return value is as like below:

```
A       B   C D
TES     T   1 ARD       
TES     T   1 BLK       
TES     T   1 FLE       
TES     T   1 HEN       
TES     T   1 RIV
```

i have to change it as like below:

```
TES     T   1 ARD,RIV,BLK,FLE,HEN,RIV
```

using c#.

c# class for above result as entity:

```
public class Entity
{
   public string A{get; set;}
   public string B{get; set;}
   public string C{get; set;}
   public string D{get; set;}
}
```

Since i'm using more than one database server like ms sql,oracle,my sql i don like to write query for each. For example: In MS SQL i have to stuff and for xml method to acheieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group entities by composite key `{ A, B, C }` and then create concatenated `D` value from all items in group:

```
var result = from e in entities // where entities is in-memory list
             group e by new { e.A, e.B, e.C } into g
             select new Entity {
                A = g.Key.A,
                B = g.Key.B,
                C = g.Key.C,
                D = String.Join(",", g.Select(e => e.D))
             };
```

You can move query execution to memory by calling `db.Entities.AsEnumerable()`. Of course, that will require downloading all table data from database to client. But if you will do grouping on server side, then you will have N+1 queries, where N is number of groups. First query will return distinct values of grouping key. Further queries will select required field by given group key value.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group by the first three columns and comma-separate the fourth column?

I'm not sure if this works with your LINQ provider, but it works in LINQ-To-Objects:

```
var query = db.Entity
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C })
    .Select(g => new Entity { 
        A = g.Key.A, B = g.Key.B, C = g.Key.C,
        D = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.D))
    });
```